# Hide div on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my script.
To show div, you have to click on link. But to hide it, you can click anywhere outside of div.
How can I make this div close only after clicking on link?

http://jsfiddle.net/N4pbP/

```
$(function() {
  $('#hidden').hide().click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });      
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    $('#hidden').animate({ opacity: "toggle" });

    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('#hidden').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Comment: why you want `$(document).click(function() {
    $('#hidden').fadeOut();
  });` function??

Comment: You already have the toggling effect on your `a`, just get rid of the `document` part.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N4pbP/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with `.blur()` like this:

```
$("a").blur(function(e) {
    $('#hidden').fadeOut();
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/N4pbP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about jquery, but I changed the code on the last function to:

```
  $document.getElementById('test').click(function() {
    $('#hidden').fadeOut();
  });
```

And it worked

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/N4pbP/3/